# Is is enough to do this as to hide data?

Tags: factory-reset

I had an optimus vu(sold) and i wanted to encrypt data but found no such option on it. I directly resetted it then started filling it up then resetted (did this process 3 times). Is it enough to make my data before the first reset be hidden or so difficult to reach?